# Why do I have to restore the iTunes Library folder permissions every time I update iTunes?

Tags: itunes

Every time there is an iTunes update, the permissions of my iTunes Library directory change. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Do you have special permissions set on the directory? If so, what?

Answer (score 1):

You could try repairing permissions on the hard drive containing your iTunes Library folder.